# Inno Setup can't delete app folder in silent uninstall

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have "Full uninstall" option for my application, which is supposed to remove all data, including ProgramData and Program Files app folders. It is decided by separate window, and folders are removed with `DelTree` method

```
Deltree(ExpandConstant('{app}'), true, true, true);
```

Deletion is executed on usPostUninstall step. But, when i make full deletion is silent mode, app folder is not removed, and i can find it in Program Files, despite it is actually empty (if it is not silent, all is deleted without problems). What can block folder deletion during silent uninstall?

Here is most simple example, using common Inno Setup example files

```
; -- UninstallCodeExample1.iss --
;
; This script shows various things you can achieve using a [Code] section for Uninstall

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Code]
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
      begin
        if not DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}'), true, true, true) then
          MsgBox('Can''t remove some files', mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
end;
```

Comment: There is probably `unins001.exe`inside that folder which is still being executed.

Comment: @Thomas that was my initial thought as well, but why it causes problem only in silent mode?

Comment: Just checked how it works now. Last files removed are not actually unins.

Comment: @Thomas Provided example

Comment: Can it be related to some UAC limitations, or something like that?

Comment: I don't know what might cause this (haven't actually tested). I'm here to warn you right now. Imagine what happens if the user *mistakenly* installs your app. say to the Program Files root (yes, some users are that *smart*). As first, if that is your application, use application data folder to store the user data (no application should ever write into its source folder). As next, there is no need for Pascal Script here, you can use the `[UninstallDelete]` section.

Comment: @TLama, as i know, `[UninstallDelete]` is processed (including all `Check` params) while installing, _before_ actual uninstallation, so it is impossible to select manually, what to remove, while uninstalling. This is why I use `[Code]` section

Comment: @TLama, and main question which concerns me, is, why it works just fine in common uninstall mode, and doesn't work in silent.

Comment: Run the uninstaller with `/silent /log=log.log` and show us the log.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl where log is actually stored?

Comment: It was just an example. You obviously use an absolute path so you know where it is stored (`/log=c:\path\log.log`).

Comment: It seems, that actions in `[Code]` section are not actually logged. So, it logs everything up to `[UninstallDelete]`, and log file simply closes. And there is no any way to get some sort of error code from DelTree, only result bool (successful or not).

Comment: Well, when it tries to delete some folders following sections orders, it gets "Failed to delete directory (145)" several times (on removing ProgramData  app folder and Start Menu folder).